# Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA save method of JpaRepository with parameter

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a total newbie in Spring and JPA and I have been following some tutorials like [this](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/)

I have applied the same idea to my application context such that I have Food and Ingredient as model class.

I have created FoodRepository by extending JpaRepository and I have created FoodController which works fine when I add the food without ingredients and the class seems like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FoodController {

    @Autowired
    FoodRepository foodRepository;

    @GetMapping("/food")
    public List<Food> getAllFoods() {
        return foodRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/food")
    public Food createFood(@Valid @RequestBody Food food) {
        return foodRepository.save(food);
    }

    @GetMapping("/food/{id}")
    public Food getFoodById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long foodId) {
        return foodRepository.findById(foodId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CRSException("Could not find the food with id: " + foodId));
    }

    @PutMapping("/food/{id}")
    public Food updateFood(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long foodId, @Valid @RequestBody Food foodDetails) {

        Food food = foodRepository.findById(foodId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CRSException("Could not find the food with id: + foodId)"));

        food.updateFood(foodDetails);

        Food updatedFood = foodRepository.save(food);
        return updatedFood;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/food/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteFood(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long foodId) {
        Food food = foodRepository.findById(foodId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CRSException("Could not find the food with id: + foodId)"));

        foodRepository.delete(food);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

I basicaly want to save a food with a list of ingredients in it, however I do not know how to modify the signature of createFood so that I can take list of ingredients parameter into method and save the food with those ingredients.

Since I am new to spring boot, jpa and hibernate; I do not know what terminology to use while searching. How can achieve this?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can set the reference of food on each ingredient by following way:

```
@PostMapping("/food")
public Food createFood(@Valid @RequestBody Food food) {
    food.getIngredients().foreach((i) -> {i.setFood(food)});
    return foodRepository.save(food);
}
```

Need to consider that your entity Food has these values:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "food", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Ingredients> ingredients;
```

Comment: I would like to manage adding Ingredients together with the Food. Assume initially I have empty database. I want to add a Food named Tomato Soup with Ingredients Tomato, Salt, Water and Pepper.(by the way Ingredient table will of course contain many Ingredient that is not in Tomato Soup like meat, onion etc)What would be the approach? Should I create Ingredient repository and add Ingredient first and later on add the Food. Even if so, how can I know which Ingredients belong to food, is there any way to take parameter to save method of food?

Comment: Well, if you want to save an ingredient by food then you need to create an IngredientRepository anyways on some case, so you'll have to create a controller for ingredients, like "/food/{foodId}/ingredients" and save each ingredient on some food.. Is this your case? Isn't it?

Comment: I have a Ingredient list in Food as property, while creating food, in the json, I will be able to pass those Ingredients too, and in the save method, I should save the Ingredients to Ingredient table and then add food and then add them each other's ingredient/food list, you mean like this?